# Starting an fragment within a view model

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, mvvm, data-binding

I'm trying to rework my studying project to use MVVM and data binding.

The project is here: https://github.com/Sophon/CriminalIntent/tree/dev

Before the rework, the app behaved like this:

- `MainActivity` hosts a `CrimeListFragment`, which is a **RecyclerView** of `Crime`s
- `CrimeHolder` implements **View.OnClickListener** and **onClick()** uses a callback function with the `id` of the `Crime` clicked
- `MainActivity` implements the callback function and starts a specific (identified with `id`) `CrimeDetailFragment` using `supportFragmentManager`
- this behavior can be seen in branch Master.

Now, while reworking, this is what I have so far:

- `list_item.xml` uses data binding
- `CrimeViewModel` has a property `crime: Crime`
- I inflate the binding in `CrimeListFragment`'s `onCreateView()`
- `CrimeHolder` class has `init { binding.viewModel = CrimeViewModel() }`
- `CrimeHolder` also has `bind(crime: Crime)` and there I assign the `crime` to the `viewModel`'s `crime`
- `CrimeListAdapter` class self explanatory
- this behavior is seen in the linked branch dev

Each crime in the **RecyclerView** is clickable, meaning `list_item.xml` will have `android:onClick="@{() -> viewModel.onCrimeClicked()}"` and `CrimeViewModel` will have a function `onCrimeClicked()`.

**My question is:** How do I start a new fragment (`CrimeDetailFragment`) from the viewmodel's `onClicked()` while complying with the MVVM architecture?

I could simply implement the **View.OnClickListener** in **Holder** like before but with MVVM I should avoid logic in **View**s (`CrimeListFragment` in my case).

Bonus question - what other changes should I implement to be more MVVM?

Comment: The point of MVVM architecture is to separate the concerns of your ViewModel from the actuals views themselves, so opening the fragment from within the viewmodel would be a bad choice.

Instead, when clicking on a crime in your recycler view, you should change the value of the selected crime in your viewmodel, such as `viewModel.setSelectedCrime(selectedCrime)`. Then, your MainActivity should be observing your viewModel, and when the `selectedCrime` has been changed, it should then launch the `CrimeDetailFragment`.

Comment: @RyanSaffer ok so I have setup a LiveData property in viewModel class. Now it's not quite clear to me how I should start with observing in MainActivity. How would MainActivity get the `binding.viewModel` that the `list_item_crime.xml` uses?

Comment: Also i'm not quite clear which viewmodel you're talking about. Each RecyclerV item has its own viewmodel so I cannot observe each one. So if you mean `CrimeListViewModel` then it's not clear to me how the fragment would know which item was selected.

Answer (score 1):

IMO,, I would create a lambda block inside Activity or Fragment and I would pass a lambda block to adapter something like:

```
private val onCrimeClicked: (Crime) -> Unit = {
    // This will be triggered later
}
private val crimeListAdapter = CrimeListAdapter(onCrimeClicked)
```

Inside the adapter, you pass the same lambda block to CrimeHolder's constructor where you are creating new CrimeHolder inside onCreateViewHolder().

Then, your CrimeHolder class may look like:

```
class CrimeHolder(private val onCrimeClicked: (Crime) -> Unit = {}){

    fun bind(crime : Crime){
        list.setOnClickListener{
            onCrimeClicked(crime)
        }
    }
}
```

See if this suits your need!

PS: This way you're no way breaking MVVM rule.

Comment: So if I understood you correctly, in Adapter class I create a function property that uses callback, then I create a Holder with that function property as parameter. Holder then creates a ViewModel instance with that function property as parameter too and in the end ViewModel's onClick() uses that function. Correct? https://gist.github.com/Sophon/3efe0afb48bdd4d1c525e64bd22da5f7

Comment: Just making sure I understood you correctly because although the code seems to work on my side, maybe I didn't understand you correctly and my code might break MVVM guidelines.